# bzr-svn out of memory error

Tags: svn, bazaar, bzr-svn

When I try to do a bzr branch from my svn repository I get an out of memory error.  The svn repository is very large.  Is there a way to give bzr more memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to branch in small steps. I.e. if you have 1000 revisions in your svn repo, try to branch by 100 revisions or so. I.e. first step

```
bzr branch URL/to/svn/repo -r100
```

Then increment revno by the 100

```
bzr pull -r200
bzr pull -r300
```

and so on.

Comment: I tried this, bzr pull -r20 works, but bzr pull -r21 fails with out of memory error.

Comment: So, about adding memory. You may want to try 2.1.0b4 or rc1 or even final which uses less memory than bzr 2.0.x. Also you may want to try to run conversion on 64-bit machine, because on 32-bit machine bzr (as being written in Python tool) can't use more than 2GB (3GB if you have enabled this in your BIOS and OS).

Please, send your question to main bzr mailing list, thus you'll have more helpful suggestions. http://lists.canonical.com/mailman/listinfo/bazaar or http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.bazaar-ng.general

Comment: When you'll finish the conversion, please send your impressions to bzr mailing list. thanks.

Comment: This is actually a (very serious) bzr limitation - it reads the files into memory. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/109114

Comment: bug 109114 is only a problem if you have very big versioned files, it's not about big repositories (with large history).